# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning

Tags: iphone

I am getting yellow warning:

**ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit, missing required architecture armv7 in file**

Have no idea what it means.

Anyone can suggest something about this yellow warning.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the SenTestingKit Framework made for the Simulator on your Device.
You might re-add SenTestingKit framework in a proper way (Targets -> Build Phases -> "press the plus", select your framework)

```
lipo -info /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit
```

gives output

```
Architectures in the fat file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit are: x86_64 i386
```

Comment: I see SenTestingKit.Framework in Link Binary With Libraries. In Target Dependencies 0 items are there. If i have to add SenTestingKit.Framework where i have to add.